# /bin/dash: Bad substitution

Tags: string, bash, sh, dash-shell, parameter-expansion

I need to do a string manipuilation in shell script (`/bin/dash`):

```
#!/bin/sh

PORT="-p7777"
echo $PORT
echo ${PORT/p/P}
```

the last echo fails with `Bad substitution`. When I change shell to bash, it works:

```
#!/bin/bash

PORT="-p7777"
echo $PORT
echo ${PORT/p/P}
```

How can I implement the string substitution in `dash` ?

Comment: FYI... I believe the proper way to switch to Bash is `#!/usr/bin/env bash`. It will work on some of the BSD's, where Bash is an add-on and installed in `/usr/local`. Confer, [Why is it better to use “#!/usr/bin/env NAME” instead of “#!/path/to/NAME” as my shebang?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29608/56041)

Comment: @jww - I don't want to switch to bash. I need to implement this in `dash`

Comment: You can use `echo $PORT | tr 'p' 'P'` to *translate* lower-p to upper-P which will not depend on the shell. You can use `tr [:lower:] [:upper:]` to translate ALL lower-case characters to upper-case.

Comment: @MartinVegter - You provided code that switched to the Bash shell.

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env` *increases* the chance of find *an* interpreter, but the correct thing to do is adjust the path to the specific path that locates the correct interpreter on *your* machine. Shebangs were never intended to address portability.

Comment: A nice page explaining how to make your script POSIX compliant, is [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using parameter expansion:

```
$ cat foo.sh
#!/bin/sh

PORT="-p7777"
echo $PORT
echo ${PORT:+-P${PORT#-p}}

PORT=""
echo $PORT
echo ${PORT:+-P${PORT#-p}}
```

Run it:

```
$ /bin/sh foo.sh
-p7777
-P7777
```

**Update**:

```
$ man dash:
- - 
${parameter#word}     Remove Smallest Prefix Pattern.

$ echo ${PORT#-p}
7777

$ man dash
- - 
${parameter:+word}    Use Alternative Value.

$ echo ${PORT:+-P${PORT#-p}}
-P7777
```

Comment: this is great. Could you please explain how it works ?

Answer (score 5):

The substitution you're using is not a basic POSIX feature (see [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html), in section 2.6.2 Parameter Expansion), and `dash` doesn't implement it.

But you can do it with any of a number of external helpers; here's an example using `sed`:

```
PORT="-p7777"
CAPITOLPORT=$(printf '%s\n' "$PORT" | sed 's/p/P/')
printf '%s\n' "$CAPITOLPORT"
```

BTW, note that I'm using `printf '%s\n'` instead of `echo` -- that's because some implementations of `echo` do unpredictable things when their first argument starts with "-". `printf` is a little more complicated to use (you need a format string, in this case `%s\n`) but much more reliable. I'm also double-quoting all variable references (`"$PORT"` instead of just `$PORT`), to prevent unexpected parsing.

I'd also recommend switching to lower- or mixed-case variables. There are a large number of all-caps variable that have special meanings, and if you accidentally use one of those it can cause problems.

Comment: You don't need a command substitution; just strip the `-p` and append the result to `-P`: `CAPITOLPORT="-P${PORT#-p}"`

Comment: @chepner  - that is not a good solution. This will put `-P` infront, whether or not the string contains `-p`. That is not what I need. The string can be empty, in which case nothing should be changed.

Comment: You never mentioned that until now.You can check if the string is nonempty and starts with `-p` with `if [ -n "$PORT" ] && [ "$PORT" != "${PORT#-p}" ]; then PORT="-P${PORT#-p}"`. Or is `PORT` an arbitrary string that might match `-p[0-9]*` *somewhere* in the middle?

Comment: @chepner - I mentioned that I am looking for equivalent of bashes `${PORT/p/P}` which works in dash.

Comment: And I'm saying you probably don't *need* the exact equivalent, if it handles cases that can never arrive in practice.

Comment: @chepner - your non-empty checking construct looks overcomplicated. More so, when the parameter expansion `${PORT:+-P${PORT#-p}}` as suggested by  @James Brown works great